# NameError: name 'linec' is not defined

Tags: python, undefined

I am new to python. I am trying to run below function, but it is showing error "NameError: name 'linec' is not defined". I am unable to understand how to get rid of this problem.

Below is my function:

```
def problem3_1(txtfilename):

    linec = 0
    wordct = 0     
    charct = 0

    text_file = open(txtfilename)
    for line in text_file:           
        linec = linec + 1
    for word in line.split():   
        wordct = wordct + 1
    charct = charct + len(line)

    text_file.close() 

print(linec, wordct, charct ) # "NameError: name 'linec' is not defined"
```

What am i doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `linec` is a variable that exists inside your function. You're trying to use it outside your function, and as far as I can see, not even calling your function.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want your variables to be global variables, not locally inside your function. What you can do is actually return those variables to create new global variables:

```
def problem3_1(txtfilename):
    linec = 0
    wordct = 0     
    charct = 0

    text_file = open(txtfilename)

    for line in text_file:           
        linec = linec + 1
        charct = charct + len(line)
        for word in line.split():   
            wordct = wordct + 1

    text_file.close()
    return linec, wordct, charct

linex, wordct, charct = problem3_1("mytxtfile.txt")
```

Finally, your character count needs to be added in the for-loop.

Comment: @PM2Ring Damn I'm rusty... fixed

Comment: @PM2Ring Fixed it

Answer (score 0):

`linec` only exists within the `problem3_1()` function. I assume you intended to call the function and return the result:

```py
def problem3_1(txtfilename):
    linec = 0
    wordct = 0     
    charct = 0

    with open(txtfilename) as text_file:
        for line in text_file:           
            linec = linec + 1
            wordct += len(line.split())
            charct += len(line)

    return linec, wordct, charct

linec, wordct, charct = problem3_1("a_text_file.txt")
print(linec, wordct, charct)
```

I also added a `with` to use a context manager to close the file. This way you can't forget to close it, it is closed automatically.

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks, fixed it

Comment: @paul23 Thanks missed that too apparently

Answer (score 0):

These variables exists only inside your function. You can make them global to print outside the function or just print them inside the function.

```
def problem3_1(txtfilename):

    linec = 0
    wordct = 0     
    charct = 0

    text_file = open(txtfilename)
    for line in text_file:           
        linec = linec + 1
    for word in line.split():   
        wordct = wordct + 1
    charct = charct + len(line)

    text_file.close() 

    print(linec, wordct, charct )
```